# Is there any standard related to django-rest-framework API building?

Tags: json, rest, django-rest-framework, standards

I'm building a REST API service on Django Rest Framework.
My project has some documentation and written requirements, however the requirements are flexible and can be changed to ease the development process.
I try to use highly abstract drf tools, like for example model viewsets, model serializers, etc.

However, sometimes project requirements are tough to fullfill using highly abstract drf tools. For example, they want a 400 if extra fields or duplicates are provided to json. So I end up writting a lot of extra checks and middlewares, which doesnt seem natural and often causes bugs. So I want to explain to my boss that we should follow some kind of a "drf way" to build our API and adjust the requirements to it.

I want to explain that drf approach is based on some kind of standards or some documents. Can somebody give an example what standards or documents I can use to stress my point?

Comment: "they want a 400 if extra fields or duplicates are provided to json."... Well, its a BAD REQUEST, seems reasonable to me? What would you return? There are no "written" rules about that. Consider a user accessing a resource that exists, but the user is not allowed to see it. You could go with 404 or 204.... The only thing the standard enforces, is, that you use defined return codes and not something like HTTP_2412_CHRISTMAS...